# Change select values with array values

Tags: php, select

Hello I have 2 select in the same form :

```
<form role="form" method="post" action="controlreservas/agregareserva.php" >
<!--ID RESIDENCIAL-->             
<?php
include "controlreservas/conexion.php";
$sql1= "select id_residencial from residenciales";
$query = $con->query($sql1);
?>
<label>Residencial</label>
<select name="id_residencial">
<?php if($query->num_rows>0):?>
<?php while ($r=$query->fetch_array()):?>
<option value="<?php echo $r["id_residencial"]; ?>"><?php echo $r["id_residencial"]; ?></option>
<?php endwhile;?>
<?php else:?>
<?php endif;?>
</select>
</div>
<!--ID RESIDENCIAL-->

<!--ID HABTIACION (NUMERO HABITACION)-->                  
<?php
include "controlreservas/conexion.php";
$sql1= "select id_residencial,id_habitacion
from habitaciones 
where id_residencial=".$_POST["id_residencial"];
$query = $con->query($sql1);
?>
<label>N&deg; Habitaci&oacute;n</label>
<select name="id_habitacion">
<?php if($query->num_rows>0):?>
<?php while ($r=$query->fetch_array()):?>
<option value="<?php echo $r["id_habitacion"]; ?>"><?php echo $r["id_habitacion"]; ?></option>
<?php endwhile;?>
<?php else:?>
<?php endif;?>
</select>
</div>
<!--ID HABTIACION (NUMERO HABITACION)-->
 <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default" style="float:left">Ingresar Reserva</button>
</form>
```

First select it´s working, Second select I need take the value how in the forms:
  `where id_residencial=".$_POST["id_residencial"];`, but I don´t know how is here (*I see codes from change values but not with arrays :/*)

Comment: Is `$_POST["id_residencial"]` a single id value or an array?

Comment: am i missing some thing, your query this one should produce a syntax error `$sql1= "select id_residencial,id_habitacion
from habitaciones 
where id_residencial=".$_POST["id_residencial"];` This is wrong, hope i am getting it right

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need one extra PHP page to  use ajax call .

```
<script src="jquery.min.js"></script> // please link the path or use cdn 
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#id_residencial').on('change',function(){
        var id_residencial = $(this).val();
        if(id_residencial){
            $.ajax({
                type:'POST',
                url:'get_id_habitacion.php',
                data:'id_residencial='+id_residencial,
                success:function(html){
                    $('#id_habitacion').html(html);
                }
            }); 
        }else{
            $('#state').html('<option value="">Select first</option>');

        }
    });

});
</script>
<!--ID RESIDENCIAL-->             
<?php
include "controlreservas/conexion.php";
$sql1= "select id_residencial from residenciales";
$query = $con->query($sql1);
?>
<label>Residencial</label>
<select name="id_residencial">
<?php if($query->num_rows>0):?>
<?php while ($r=$query->fetch_array()):?>
<option value="<?php echo $r["id_residencial"]; ?>"><?php echo $r["id_residencial"]; ?></option>
<?php endwhile;?>
<?php else:?>
<?php endif;?>
</select>
</div>
<!--ID RESIDENCIAL-->
<!--ID HABTIACION (NUMERO HABITACION)-->                  
<select name="id_habitacion">
</select>
</div>
<!--ID HABTIACION (NUMERO HABITACION)-->
 <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default" style="float:left">Ingresar Reserva</button>
</form>
```

Create a new php file say "get_id_habitacion.php" with code

```
<?php
$id_residencial=$_POST["id_residencial"];
$sql2= "select id_residencial,id_habitacion
from habitaciones 
where id_residencial='$id_residencial';
$query2 = $con->query($sql2);
?>
<label>N&deg; Habitaci&oacute;n</label>
<?php if($query2->num_rows>0):?>
<?php while ($r2=$query2->fetch_array()):?>
<option value="<?php echo $r2["id_habitacion"]; ?>"><?php echo $r2["id_habitacion"]; ?></option>
<?php endwhile;?>
<?php else:?>
<?php endif;?>
```

Note : 1) Check the database (must be proper connected and have some data)
       2) Check variable (Since i have not tested and run the code)
       3) If problem exist ,  check  "get_id_habitacion.php" using "localhost/project_name/get_id_habitacion.php" (remember to replace the second line of get_id_habitacion.php with a contact variable eg $id_residencial='5';)
         4) use proper link for jquery.min.js or use its cdn

Comment: at least explain to her, what you change, i know what you change but she dont, and it's her question, thanks

Comment: Tengo este error: Notice: Undefined index: id_residencial in C:\EasyPHP-Devserver-16.1\eds-www\vicmar\reservas\calendario2.php on line 21

Comment: I put isset:  $id_residencial=isset($_POST["id_residencial"]); and this error not show, but again the first select its ok and 2do not show , I think I have put something in the select (onchange ?)  I don´t know :/

Comment: @Diana Letelier , 1) Do you want the result of first select to generate the query result for second select ???? 2) i would like to exlain your requirement more clear (possible in steps )

Comment: @kashif yes exact, for example residenciales have id_residencial, have 3 ids [1,2,3] and then habitaciones have (id_habitacion,id_residencial) , (habitacion = room , residencial = Residential), so when I add a room I put the residencial that this room is.... then when I add reservation I have this 2 select first I said where residential and the 2d select I said the room .

Comment: @Diana Letelier , i would recommend you to  use AJAX  for this purpose , do you want the solution with that (AJAX) ?

Comment: @Kashif yes, but I don't how, if you know please tell me. (I search in the internet just in case, but the answers are diferent, no specific with my code, and how I speak spanish don´t understand very good how to use the code or adapted to my)

Comment: @Diana Letelier check the latest code .  And frame your problems and words in steps :)

Comment: @Kashif it´s working :D:D I put in the select  id="id_residencial" and 2d id="id_habitacion"  because they have name only and  in the get_id_habitacion.php. y put    "    in the final where id_residencial='$id_residencial'";    and it´s working, 
thank you very very much, i vote

Comment: @Diana Letelier My pleasure :)

Comment: kashif , hello and sorry but you know how use ajax but with datepicker, I put other ask question , if you can see, thanks... http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41211430/datepicker-show-click-button-after-ajax-where-idid

Comment: @Diana , i found No Question there ?

Comment: @kashif yes but now is with buttons and dates i am try http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41214771/call-ajax-function-onclick-button-and-success-datepicker

Comment: @Diana . Please explain your problem and requirement in points , and also show your piece of code

Comment: @kashif yes the problem it's here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41214771/call-ajax-function-onclick-button-and-success-datepicker

Comment: @Diana ok . i will see it .